# Asp.net - Add blank item at top of dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Why is the dropdown not showing my blank item first? Here is what I have

```
drpList.Items.Add(New ListItem("", ""))

With drpList
    .DataSource = myController.GetList(userid)
    .DataTextField = "Name"
    .DataValueField = "ID"
    .DataBind()
End With
```

Edit ~ I am binding to a Generig List, could this be the culprit?

Comment: This relates to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983716/asp-net-dropdownlist-add-blank-line-before-db-values

Answer (score 285, accepted):

After your databind:

```
drpList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
drpList.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Alternately, you can instantiate a ListItem, set its Selected property to true, and then insert it into drpList as above.

Comment: *This may help those looking for an answer to work with sqlDataSource data*  In my case, I also had to add drpList.AppendDataBoundItems = true; to bind it to the current data in the Page_Load method

Answer (score 34):

You can use `AppendDataBoundItems=true` to easily add:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpList" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: VS doesn't like the <br /> tag and it works for me without it. This is such a clean option, I don't know why it doesn't have more votes.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the design time solution.

Comment: Don't forget to set Selected="true"

Answer (score 25):

The databinding takes place after you've added your blank list item, and it replaces what's there already, you need to add the blank item to the beginning of the List from your controller, or add it after databinding.

EDIT:

After googling this quickly as of ASP.Net 2.0 there's an "AppendDataBoundItems" true property that you can set to...append the databound items.

for details see

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=281 or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx

Comment: One think you need to watch out for is having your dropdown list grow after each postback by appending the same data over and over.

Comment: Is the blank item not there, or there but just not selected?

Comment: This would work if you had the blank one in your .aspx markup, then bound in code behind.

Answer (score 13):

I think a better way is to insert the blank item first, then bind the data just as you have been doing. However you need to set the `AppendDataBoundItems` property of the list control.

We use the following method to bind any data source to any list control...

```
public static void BindList(ListControl list, IEnumerable datasource, string valueName, string textName)
{
    list.Items.Clear();
    list.Items.Add("", "");
    list.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    list.DataValueField = valueName;
    list.DataTextField = textName;
    list.DataSource = datasource;
    list.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Like "Whisk" Said, the trick is in "AppendDataBoundItems" property

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks "Whisk"

Answer (score 5):

Do your databinding and then add the following:

```
Dim liFirst As New ListItem("", "")
drpList.Items.Insert(0, liFirst)
```

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you are adding a blank item, and then databinding, which would empty the list; try inserting the blank item after databinding

Comment: when I do that, the blank row appears at the bottom.

Comment: You can specify the index to insert into. Look at JasonS' solution.

Comment: @[Saif Khan]: and if that doesn't work, insert the blank row into your datasource, then databind

Answer (score 3):

simple

at last

```
ddlProducer.Items.Insert(0, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

`ddlCategory.DataSource = ds;`
`ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CatName";`
`ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CatID";`

Cách 1:

`ddlCategory.Items.Add(new ListItem("--please select--", "-1"));`
`ddlCategory.AppendDataBoundItems = true;`
`ddlCategory.SelectedIndex = -1;`

`ddlCategory.DataBind();`

Cách 2:

`ddlCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- please select --", "0"));`

**(Tested OK)**

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a union of the blank select with the select that has content:

```
select '' value, '' name
union
select value, name from mytable
```

Comment: Looking back, I wouldn't recommend this method except only as an alternative.  I like the event for flexibility sake (OnDataBound="mydropdown_DataBound"), but in my current case, I'm adopting the (AppendDataBoundItems="true") for simplicity sake.