# populate dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi i need to populate a dropdownlist. I designed a datasource and assigned it to dropdownlist. The dropdown populated correctly. But the problem is that i need to add a default value say "default" at the starting of the dropdownlist( and this value default is not in the database.

I did this :

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="classInstructor" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
                DataTextField="InstrName" DataValueField="InstrName">

        <asp:ListItem Value="Default" Text="Default" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>


        </asp:DropDownList>
```

But default doesn't show up on dropdown. Probably, the way i did was wrong. Can u let me know the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `AppendDataBoundItems` property to `true` on the dropdown list and the items from the data source will appear after any ListItems you add in the markup e.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="classInstructor" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
    DataTextField="InstrName" DataValueField="InstrName" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Default" Text="Default" Selected="True"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: wow I did not know this one, if it works, question I linked in my answer was pointless!?

Comment: @Davide I was just looking at your answer and thinking 'we can't **both** be right' :-) Bear in mind that when the DataSourceId is set declaratively in the markup, there is no explicit call to `DataBind`, it all happens automagically.

Comment: @Davide Have a look at the second answer in the question you linked to, it also talks about this property.

Comment: yeah that's true but still could be possible to call Insert in the Page_PreRender. if everything done purely from markup side and your solution works, all good. my solution and what I linked is valid for a code based binding/approach.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use this approach if the DropDownList is bound to a datasource at runtime this Default item you have in the markup at design time will be washed away in the binding.

what you need to do is an `Insert` after the call to the `DataBind()` method.

see here for the examples and more comments on this: [Asp.net - Add blank item at top of dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267064/asp-net-add-blank-item-at-top-of-dropdownlist)