# data binding to dropdownlist in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

For a Label in we bind a data using

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label>
```

how to bind data to dropdownlist like that?

```
asp:DropDownList ID="droplist" runat="server" >
     <asp:ListItem Text="admin"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="manager"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this....

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="droplist" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("fieldname")%>'>
     <asp:ListItem Text="admin"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="manager"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Note that intellisense will not pick SelectedValue out. You will of course need to populate the dropdown with the data... using any method that suits

Comment: This works, t.y. noting about IntelliSense not picking this out. That was bugging me:(

Answer (score 0):

Either put your datasource in the DropDownList declaration like here: [populate dropdownlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590365/populate-dropdownlist)

Or use Codebehind like this:

Eg: inside Page_Load():

```
List<string> ItemsToGoInDropDown = new List<string>{"manager", "admin", "etc"};
droplist.DataSource = ItemsToGoInDropDown;
droplist.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the data in hidden field. Then asigen that in drop down in Gridview Rowdatabound Event.Like This.

```
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hf");
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl");
            ddl.SelectedValue = hf.Value;
        }
```