# Set a default value for my dropdownlist which is filled from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm filling my dropdownlist from database but I want to add **"select an item please"** to the dropdown along with others and make it default selected item :
I tried to set`writerddl.SelectedValue = "please...";`but a runtime error says:

> 'writerddl' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not
>   exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

and here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
writerddl.SelectedValue = "please...";
if (!IsPostBack)
  {
   writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
   writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
   writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname";            
   writerddl.DataBind();
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267064/asp-net-add-blank-item-at-top-of-dropdownlist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
       writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
       writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname";            
       writerddl.DataBind();
       writerddl.Items.insert(0, new ListItem("Please select",""));
   }
}
```

Comment: aha okay I'll try this

Comment: This is the correct way. Also note, the 0 at the beginning is the index as to where to insert the item. If you are dealing with this dropdown in jQuery, ensure you handle this insert..

Comment: mmm ... okay ... but it doesn't work if I removed the "`if (!isPostback)`"

Comment: because when page post back happened if there is no  if (!isPostback) drop down will reload again and again

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
writerddl.SelectedValue = "please...";
```

and use this:

```
//....    
writerddl.DataBind();
writerddl.Items.Insert(0, "please...");
//...
```

***Update:***

use Clear() method like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   writerddl.Items.Clear();
   writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
   writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
   writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname";            
   writerddl.DataBind();
   writerddl.Items.Insert(0, "please...");
}
```

Comment: where in the code ? you mean instead of writerddl.SelectedValue = "please..."; ?

Comment: mmm ... okay ... but it doesn't work if I removed the "`if (!isPostback)`"

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code. Note the selected-value line moved below and that makes difference. Hope the item with Value "please..." exists in the dropdown.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
            writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
            writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname";
            writerddl.DataBind();
            writerddl.SelectedValue = "please...";
        }

    }
```

**Update :** 
"Hope the item with Value "please..." exists in the dropdown" changing this line to "Hope the item with Value "please..." exists in the binding source".

**Update 1:**
    If the source don't have item "please..." here is the below code.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        writerddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select An Item", "please..."));
        writerddl.DataSource = DS.show_all_writers();
        writerddl.DataValueField = "writerid";
        writerddl.DataTextField = "writersname";
        writerddl.DataBind();
        writerddl.SelectedValue = "please...";
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the point of the OP's post is that the "please..." does NOT exist in the datasource, but he wants it added.

Comment: @paqogomez Is it possible to select an item before binding?. For the first load the code is trying to select before binding. I am trying to point out that. In comment i also added "hope the item with Value "please..." exists in the dropdown".

Comment: You are correct in pointing that out, but incorrect in delivering a working solution.

Comment: I think you need to write it so that you assume that the value is NOT in the datasource.